# How to understand the JavaScript code generated by CoffeeScript's `extends` keyword

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, prototypal-inheritance

This is the JavaScript code generated by CoffeeScript's `extends` keyword. How the prototype chain gets setup?

```
var __hasProp = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,
__extends = function(child, parent) { 
    for (var key in parent) { 
        if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; 
    } 
    function ctor() { this.constructor = child; } 
    ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; 
    child.prototype = new ctor; 
    child.__super__ = parent.prototype; 
    return child; 
};
```

Comment: Which part is giving you trouble?

Comment: do not understand this line: `ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; `

Comment: My blog post details that. `ctor` is called a *surrogate* constructor. It's a separate constructor that you copy the prototype of the parent to. It sets up the prototype chain `child.prototype = new ctor` without having to call the parent's constructor just for setting up inheritance. The more known (but problematic) way of setting inheritance is by doing `child.prototype = new parent`. Again, my blog post goes into details of what are the problems with that

Comment: I read your blog post. Very thorough explanation. The key thing is understanding "surrogate constructor". Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var __hasProp = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,
__extends = function(child, parent) {
    // Copy "static" attributes from the parent constructor to the child constructor
    for (var key in parent) { 
        if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; 
    } 
    // This is the surrogate constructor, used so you don't need
    // to instantiate an instance of the parent just to setup the prototype chain
    // the statement in the surrogate constructor properly attaches
    // the constructor property to object
    function ctor() { this.constructor = child; }
    // Attach the parent's prototype to the surrogate constructor
    ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; 
    // This is setting up the chain, attaching an instance of a constructor whose
    // prototype is set to the parent to the prototype property of the child
    // In naive implementations, this would be child.prototype = new parent();
    child.prototype = new ctor; 
    // Allows access to the parent from user code, and used by the `super` keyword
    child.__super__ = parent.prototype; 
    return child; 
};
```

See http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/08/javascript-inheritance-done-right.html (my own blog post)

Comment: I know it wasn't the part the OP was interested in, but do you know why this code uses `__hasProp` like that? I don't understand how that helps compared to saying `if (parent.hasOwnProperty(key))`...

Comment: It's so it still works even if a property `parent.hasOwnProperty` has been overwritten on the parent. Sometimes written as `{}.hasOwnProperty.call(parent, key)`